# Refresh token issue AuthenticationInterceptor for Alamofire 5

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, token, alamofire

I implemented the new AuthenticationInterceptor into my app, here is my actual code:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

struct OAuthCredential: AuthenticationCredential {
    let accessToken: String
    let refreshToken: String
    let expiration: Date

    // Require refresh if within 5 minutes of expiration
    var requiresRefresh: Bool { Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 15) > expiration }
}

class OAuthAuthenticator: Authenticator {
    func apply(_ credential: OAuthCredential, to urlRequest: inout URLRequest) {
        urlRequest.headers.add(.authorization(bearerToken: credential.accessToken))
    }

    func refresh(_ credential: OAuthCredential, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<OAuthCredential, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        NetworkManager.shared.oauth.doRefreshToken { (jsonDict, error) in
            if let jsonDict = jsonDict {
                let json = JSON(jsonDict)
                let accessToken = json["access_token"].stringValue
                let refreshToken = json["refresh_token"].stringValue
                let expiration = json["expires_in"].doubleValue
                let newCredential = OAuthCredential(accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken, expiration: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: expiration))
                completion(.success(newCredential))
            }
        }
    }

    func didRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, with response: HTTPURLResponse, failDueToAuthenticationError error: Error) -> Bool {
        return response.statusCode == 401
    }

    func isRequest(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, authenticatedWith credential: OAuthCredential) -> Bool {
        let bearerToken = HTTPHeader.authorization(bearerToken: credential.accessToken).value
        return urlRequest.headers["Authorization"] == bearerToken
    }
}
```

The problem here is when for example I enter a screen where there're 3 API calls, refresh delegate is called also 3 times and refresh the token 3 times also.

What I want to achieve is to call "doRefreshToken" once and recall all APIs with the new token.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier also with its methods.

Here is a good answer by @m1sh0

[Alamofire auto refresh token and retry previous API call in iOS Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963748/alamofire-auto-refresh-token-and-retry-previous-api-call-in-ios-swift-4/56965479#56965479)